# Determining size of AppendRows request message

Tags: go, google-bigquery

I am using the Golang Storage API library to write to BigQuery. For this I am calling `AppendRows()` https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery/storage/managedwriter#ManagedStream.AppendRows.
This function has a limitation that the request size cannot be more than 10 MB otherwise an error will be returned. One way I can avoid this is to send the data in smaller chunks. But I do not want to send too small chunks and want to send as much data as possible in a chunk.

So, I want to know if there is a way I can determine the request size before sending the data to the function? This would help me to adjust the size of the message and not keep adding the data to the request.

Comment: Hi @ABeginner, You can Restructure the job so that each component generates smaller requests. This can be done by Sending requests with fewer rows more often, or by checking the size of the data you are trying to send and split it into several requests if needed. Using ‘bq load’ if you insert a single long row. Splitting into multiple requests if there are multiple rows. Let me know if this helps or not?

Comment: @PrajnaRaiT Yes, that  is one option but I do not want to do that unless there is no better way. There is a restriction here that I have to always send data not more than a certain threshold. And this is not really sending and using the 10 MB request size as much as possible because of the threshold restriction. If I can determine the size of either the entire request or just the part excluding the actual data I would be able to achieve the goal of using 10MB request as much as possible.

Comment: Hi @ABeginner Keen to know if dry run mentioned in my post is an option for you?

Comment: @BihagKashikar This doesn't fulfill my requirement. The dry run method will give me an estimate on only the data size. Furthermore, I am using storage API and not jobs API. Storage API requires you to send request in a message which can be larger than the actual data processed.

Comment: @ABeginner Understand now a bit better. Another question, where are you hosting this code? Cloud Function or somewhere else? asking this to asses feasibility of creating a intermediate bypass/passthrough http service hosted on cloud function which can accept your messages and then use req.get("content-length") to get size of the request, based on which you can then further chunks in you actual go lang code? option feasible only if you have hosted the code in gcp. hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

One options is to execute a dry run before sending the data to function.

The code snippet of the dry one using Golang is given [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-query-dry-run#code-sample). The dry run will give estimate the number of bytes read by the query. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

For your requirement, you can consider the option mentioned by @BihagKashikar.

Other option is to, Restructure the job so that each component generates smaller requests. This can be done by Sending requests with fewer rows more often, or by checking the size of the data you are trying to send and split it into several requests if needed.
Using ‘bq load’ if you insert a single long row. Splitting into multiple requests if there are multiple rows.

For more information you can refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas).